# React Native: Update Text Inside a Variable

Tags: react-native

I have a variable that contains a text element. This text element has to be a variable and I need to change the text displayed. This is my code:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { Button, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

    type Props = {};
    export default class App extends Component<Props> {

    // Initializes testval and testItem.
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   

        this.state = {
            testval:0,
        }


        this.testItem =
            <Text
                style={{
                    position:'absolute',
                    left:50,
                    top:200,
                    backgroundColor:'white',
                }}
                >
                Value: {this.state.testval}
            </Text>
    }


    // Call `UpdateTest` after some time.
    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(this.UpdateTest, 1000);     
    }


    // Updates the test value.
    UpdateTest = () => {
        this.setState({
            testval:this.state.testval+1,
        });
    }


    // Renders the test items.
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                // Display the text item.
                {this.testItem}             

            </View>
        )
    }
    }

    const styles = {
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'aqua',
        }
    }
```

The text is displayed, but the displayed `testval` does not change. Can anyone help?  I need to know how to cause RN to re-render a text element contained in a variable when a state change occurs.

Note:

- In the actual project, text must be created in the constructor as demonstrated.
- If I replace '{this.testItem}' in 'render' with the `<Text>` block it contains, then I see the `testval` change, but as stated, I need to contain the text in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't define this in render which will recompute with state changes?

```
render() {
  const { testVal } = this.state
  testItem = (
    <Text
      style={{
        position:'absolute',
        left:50,
        top:200,
        backgroundColor:'white',
      }}
    >
      Value: {testval}
    </Text>
  )
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {testItem}             
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, the element has to be defined outside of `render` because, in the actual project, the text position is animated, and therefore has to be created once.

Comment: @BrianA.Lee and you can't accomplish this with Animated. components where the position is stored as an Animated.Value()

Comment: Ok, let's forget about the Animated part. Given the code stated, and given that the `testItem` has to be created in the constructor, is there any way to modify the text in the `testItem`?

Comment: @BrianA.Lee, id look into forceUpdate() https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: thank you so much for your time and assistance. I will give this a shot.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I added `this.forceUpdate();` to `UpdateTest`, but the value did not change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentDidUpdate` and reassign the value of your `testItem`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      testval: 0
    }

    this.testItem = (
      <Text
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 50,
          top: 200,
          backgroundColor: 'white'
        }}
      >
        Value: {this.state.testval}
      </Text>
    )
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.testItem = (
      <Text
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left: 50,
          top: 200,
          backgroundColor: 'white'
        }}
      >
        Value: {this.state.testval}
      </Text>
    )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.updateTest, 1000)
  }

  updateTest = () => {
    this.setState({ testval: this.state.testval + 1 })
  }

  render() {
    return <View style={styles.container}>{this.testItem}</View>
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but the `testItem` has to be created once in the constructor, due to project restrictions.

Comment: I just updated my answer. You are still creating ```testItem``` in the constructor, but you are assigning a new value to it in ```componentDidUpdate```.

Comment: Thank you, but the text can only be created once, due to project restrictions. The problem is, because the text is inside a variable, RN is not re-rendering it on the state change. I need to know how to cause RN to re-render a text element contained in a variable when a state change occurs.

Comment: I understand. However, I'm afraid you're wrong when you say "RN is not re-rendering it on the state change". RN (or just React in this case) re-renders the screen as usual on state change - you can log this in your render method if you want to see it. However, the value you assigned to your variable is not changing on state change - you create this variable in your constructor method and its value won't change unless you update it on re-render.

Comment: Thanks. I am updating the contents of the Text periodically, but not the `this.state.testval` variable. It seems this is a case RN will not re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand the problem. When the `testItem` is created, the variable `this.state.testval` is evaluated. `Text` element contains this evaluation and not the variable. Therefore, changing the variable does nothing.

To solve this problem, I created a separate class which has a function to set the variable value, and a `render` function that uses the value.

```
class SuperText extends React.Component<Props> {

inval = 0;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
}

SetInval = (val) => {
    this.inval = val;
}

render() {
    return (
            <Text
                style={this.props.style}
                >
                Value: {this.inval}
            </Text>                         
    )
}   

}
```

Thanks to all that offered help.